# perl cut variable after match

Tags: perl, cut

I have a variable in the directory where some logs are stored. I would like to get the word after "logs" in the path (kelvin and james for case below), the "logs" will be fixed among all paths.

Example path defined in variable

```
Both possible:
my $path1="/path/to/abc/logs/kelvin/";
my $path2="/path/to/abc/logs/james";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A match in list context returns the captured substrings, so we can use a match with a simple regex pattern to extract the desired portion.

```perl
my ( $id ) = $path =~ m{/logs/([^/]*)};
```